# In woocommerce, is it possible to make payment of one customer order by another customer?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce, is it possible to make payment of one customer order by another customer ?

i.e. If customer **A** place an order and customer **B** make payment of this order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about WooCommerce are being considered off topic here, as it is a 3rd party library. You can try [the support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce/) or the woocommerce.com support instead

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible.

An order could be generated either via customer A or via the orders screen on the backend.

I'm unaware of a way to get the URL to pay from any admin screens as an existing feature but there is a function to get the payment URL.

You would basically pass in the order ID of customer **A** and it will show the URL to give to customer **B**. Use the following snippet where `$order_id` is the order number of customer **A**:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$pay_url = esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() );
echo $pay_url;
```